# Simple way to sign data with Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature

I need a very simple way to sign data with Metamask and Web3. I am very familiar with using eth sign and eth personal sign with Web3, but I want to incorporate Metamask into it. I have read the Metamask docs on signing data, but the examples they gave are outdated.

Any suggestions on a very simple way to sign data?